# How to add a comment to an answer?

Tags: support, comment, answers, privileges

I see in some questions, Other are adding comments to an answer. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

When you get 50 reputation you can [Comment Everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

As Michael Albanese commented, the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) mentions that you can comment on any of your own questions or answers and on any answers to your questions, even with a reputation of 1. You should see an "add comment" link to the lower left of the comments to your question and each answer to your question.

Comment: but when I have more question, how can I ask the answerer?

Comment: @maple: According to the [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), in particular the comment after the dagger, you can comment on any answers to your own question, even if you have less than $50$ reputation.